# Creating internal file in android

Tags: android, file

I want to create a file in android application during runtime. As i understand i can do it using :

```
openFileOutput("samplefile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

The problem is, i want to create this file in another class not in Activity. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send context instance as parameters of method in  your second class

```
public class classOI{

    public void writeToFile(Context ctx,String string,String FILENAME){

    try{
      FileOutputStream fos = ctx.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      fos.write(string.getBytes());
      fos.close();
      }catch(Exception e){
        //log for error
      }
    }
}
```

now you can call it like this in you main activilty :

```
new classOI().writeToFile(this,"text to write","myFile");
```

Comment: you can specify the path of the file you've created in the file name or not ?? example ( new classOI().writeToFile(this,"text to write", "android/data/myfile.txt");

Comment: Where this file is stored in android system?

Comment: It should be @ /data/data/packageName/files/FILENAME